# What the s*!+ do I do to make the 4.2 swipe keyboard stop censoring me?

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, auto-correct

The new swype-style keyboard on my 4.2.1 updated Galaxy Nexus is great. However, when I  attempt to express myself more colorfully, the swiping action does not yield the word I would like to write. The word is already in the device dictionary though, so it does not let me add it to the dictionary to be recognized, as I have done with other words. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just had a hunt round myself (also on a 4.2.1 Galaxy Nexus) my "Google Voice Typing" settings does not have "Block Offensive Words" selected. I can type offensive words by tapping the keyboard keys without any problem, I just can't "swipe" them, even if its the exact same word I just tapped out with no problem. Can't see any swipe setting to allow all words.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I what I will call a workaround for the present, as it is not a simple solution as allowing offensive words in voice typing, but it has the same final affect:

1. Under Settings, choose `Language & Input`
2. Choose `Personal Dictionary`
3. Click the plus (+) button in the top right
4. Enter the "offensive word" under the `Phrase` and `Shortcut` spaces
5. Click the back button (system or top left)
6. Enjoy your custom swipable profanity

Comment: You should accept this answer since it's the best and "only" solution I've found that works.

Comment: I swear! Often! And somebody should make a personal dictionary app preloaded with all the color language you could possibly want. I'd pay for that.

Answer (score 7):

I have a Nexus 4 from T-Mobile, the Google one, with Android 4.2.2. I've been noticing this same problem, and the fix I found was to go to **Settings -> Language and Input** -> Then press the settings icon next to the **Google Keyboard (English, U.S.)** option -> then deselect **Block offensive words.**

I can now swype swear words, although often times it is not the automatically recognized word, and I have to manually select it from the list of other possibilities that comes up. As for the voice-to-text options, I would suggest trying the same thing (i.e. finding it under **Settings** and deselecting **Block offensive words** or some similar option). Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't seem to allow swiping the word directly, but it does offer auto correct options to the intended profanity.. sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Some keyboards have a kind of "blacklist" for bad/insulting words. Check if you can find that option in *Settings → Language & Input*, where you should be able to disable it. I know for sure there's such an option for voice input ("Block insults" in *Settings → Voice Input & Output → Voice recognizer Settings*), but I'm not sure whether *that* option also applies to keyboard input.

Comment: Can confirm that the Voice typing "Block Offensive Words" setting doesn't apply to swiping. I can't find any equivalent for swiping.